# Visio macro to save a macro-free file

Tags: vba, visio

I have a series of complex charts to draw, so I have written a macro that takes a set of instructions from a CSV file and draws them appropriately.  This works, but I need to manually save the produced page as a .vsdx file (i.e. without my macro code) after the fact.

What I'd like to do is specify the filename in the input file and have it produce a macro-free visio file of that name.

I've tried

```
Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs filename
```

but this immediately generates a run-time error: "VB projects cannot be saved in macro-free files".

I understand that - I don't *want* my macro code in each of the (dozens of) flow charts I'm drawing.  How can I suppress this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to store your macros in the drawing files. Save them instead in a stencil, make a template with that stencil loaded and start new drawings from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have your macro(s) stored in a document file, then you'd want to have your macro generate a new document in which you draw your complex charts.  But as @y4cine commented, you need to keep your code separate from your content, if you want to save your content as macro-free files.

Otherwise you may be able to set Application.AlertResponse to whatever response Visio asks interactively when you try to save a file that has a macro as a macro-free format.

Comment: Right - so the solution is to either (a) create a stencil and put the macro there or (b) have the macro generate a whole new document as part of the process?  (I'll also try the "cheap and cheerful" approach of automatically hiding the prompt, but I'm less optimistic of this, as I don't get the prompt from the macro - just a run-time error).

Comment: Yeah that pretty much sums it up.